# Urlopen works for some urls but for others throws urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, urlopen

I was trying to setup tensorflow and I find myself in middle of a strange problem. Upon investigating the code. I found that code is using urlopen to fetch the file so I tried different things with it. the result is that

```
urlopen('https://www.google.com', None)
```

works fine 
but

```
urlopen('https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz', None)
```

throws exception.

`<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>`

Comment: It seems unlikely the problem is with `urllib`. Can you reach the failing url from the command line (e.g. using `curl`)? I'm guessing you'll see the same failure, which suggests this is some sort of local network problem (firewall? ISP having a bad day?).

Comment: @larsks silly that i didn't try this, you are right it (this particular url, all others i tested are working) doesn't work even with curl . But it doesn't work from one particular machine and works in all others in network.